# Java Final Keyword vs C++ const pointer vs C++ reference

Tags: java, c++

as I see it C++ constant pointer, C++ reference and Java final keyword (final on a variable) are all the same thing or at least act the same way.

they prevent the variable to change his "pointed address" but the internal value can be changed.

am I right for thinking that?

If not what are the differences?

regarding the c++ part
what are the differences between a constant pointer and a reference?
they look like a different way to do the same thing, why adding the reference concept to c++ if the concept already existed in the form of constant pointer?

regarding the Java part
is there a way(in Java) to simulate the same behavior of a pointer to a constant value of c++? basically is there a way to make constant values?
something more similar to `const Shape* s = new Shape;`

edit: I found at least 1 reason to introduce the reference concept
when we define a copy constructor we need to get the object as an argument and without a reference, we will get an infinite loop

C++:

```
class Shape{
public:
   int member = 3;
};



Shape s1;
Shape s2;

Shape* const cp_var_1 = &s1;
cp_var_1->member = 5; // valid
cp_var_1 = &s2; //not valid


Shape& ref_var_2 = s1;
ref_var_2.member = 6; // valid - s1 changed as well

// cant change ref_var_2 to reference other variable (like s2) 
ref_var_2 = s2;
// assignment operator called - s1 and s2 content are the same
// but ref_var_2 still reference s1
```

Java:

```
class Shape{
   public int member = 3;
}

Shape s1 = new Shape();
Shape s2 = new Shape();

final Shape final_var_3 = s1;
final_var_3.member = 7; // valid
final_var_3 = s2; // not valid
```

Comment: Different languages are different. Don't try to reason about C++ with Java (and vice-versa).

Comment: constant pointer- you can't point to different varibale, c++ reference is just like passing variable address and java final variable is constant variable you can't change its value

Comment: The latest c++ standard also has a [`final`keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final).

Comment: All of these concepts you're mentioning are completely unrelated regarding `final`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Not strictly a keyword (that would be a breaking change), but a *specifier*. Similar to `override`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're precisely correct: in `final var_3 = s1;`, the `final` prevents you from ever making `var_3` reference anything else, but you can dereference the variable and do whatever you want to what you find there: `var_3.member = 7;` is therefore valid (the dot is the dereference operator).

Note that the `final` keyword in java is used for different purposes. You can mark classes as final, which means they cannot be extended. (`class Foo extends SomeClassMarkedFinal {}` will not compile). `final` can also be applied to methods: In that case, it means any subclass may not override this method. Whilst the english name `final` does seem like a good term for all of this behaviour, the `final` as used on variable declarations, and the `final` as used on methods and classes, are otherwise utterly unrelated.

Many java types (such as `java.lang.String`, `java.lang.Integer`, and many more) are so-called 'immutable': These objects have absolutely no way to change anything about them. java's strings are objects (not ersatz char arrays), you can't access the underlying char array, there is no `clear()` or `setChar()` method, etc: Therefore, a final variable of type string is completely constant.

Java does not (currently) offer any way of marking a type as 'constant' in this sense, and it probably wouldn't make much sense to add this as a notion. For example, in java, `java.io.File`, which represents a file path, is immutable: It has absolutely no methods to mutate any of its state.

And yet, is it immutable? Is it 'constant'? If I run file.delete(), I can most assuredly observe a change, even though the object itself (which has just one field, of type string, containing a file path) hasn't changed at all.

Comment: You are wrong about java.io.File. It is immutable. Which is different from the actual file it is handling. Which is not apart of the structure. That is the business of the OS. I however have some problems with the API. 1. It is the only java class that has directory listing. 2. It is hard to parse file branches with File.

Comment: I said that j.i.File is immutable and it is; what am I wrong about? Maybe read it again, more carefully, if it confuses you. Paths/Files is the newer API to let you list dirs (so, 'it is the only java class' is not a correct statement); it even has support for file walking (more than j.i.File does). Perhaps it is time to update your knowledge of java's I/O APIs :)

Comment: Actually you should update your knowledge of my android.content.Intent. As android does not support java non blocking api, unless you are target the latest latest android api level. Finally I did not misread your comment. You said Strings  are completed constant but j.i.File are not.

Comment: "For example, in java, java.io.File, which represents a file path, is immutable".

Answer (score -1):

The `final` keyword in java does have (basically) the same effect as a reference or constant pointer in c++, but `const` in c++ ends up being a lot more general and more powerful.

If you have a pointer or a reference to a `const` object, then the object itself should be regarded as immutable. For example, if a function takes a const reference to an object, I can safely pass in objects with the assumption that they won’t be modified. And if I write a `const` member function, then I’m promising that that member function won’t modify the underlying object.

Adding `const` to function parameters (especially those passed by reference or pointer) can make it a lot easier for programmers to reason about code. They know that they can expect those inputs to remain unchanged. This is an enormous benefit when tracking down bugs, and it makes it easier to reason about the interface for external libraries that use `const` properly.

Finally, unlike in Java, a function that takes a value by reference in C++ is allowed (and encouraged) to assume that the reference you passed it isn’t null. This is good. If you write your code so that your references are never null, the code will be simpler, cleaner, and faster (since you won’t have to do null checks) .

Comment: "assuming a reference isn't null" does not make sense. references cannot be null in c++

Comment: @idclev you dont know what you talking. A reference is just a pointer which is auto dereference and surely can be null. Also what a reference pointd to surely can be altered. Check out the answer I am about to write.

Comment: @JaveneCPPMcGowan "A reference is just a pointer" no. "... and surely can be null." no. " Also what a reference pointd to surely can be altered." no. Maybe you are talking about something different, i was talking about references in c++